# How to represent a string as binary tree in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Hi there I'm kinda new to programing and I have to check if a given binary tree is balanced or not in Java. to do so I wanted to try to reach the deepest node of both sides and check the difference in height but the thing is the trees are given like this:
AAAxxxAxx where A are nodes and x are null so this example would look something like this:

```
       A

    A     A

 A
```

Problem is I have no idea how to represent the string as a binary tree. 
I had an idea and tried adding each character to an Arraylist but soon after I gave up.
sorry if my question is dumb or something but I really have no idea what to do.
any tips or help would be appreciated or if anyone has a better idea of how to check if the tree is balanced please let me know.
thank you in advance.

Comment: How does `AAAxxxAxx` relate to the tree you drew? I don't understand, can you add the xs on the drawing?

Comment: There are many different definitions of "balanced." Do you mean perfectly balanced?

Comment: @Bentaye, I think the string is constructed in a preorder traversal of the tree. I will propose an edit to add the xs

Answer (score 2):

A common way to represent a binary tree in an array is:

- If root position is `i`
- Left child is `2*i+1`
- Right child is `2*i+2`
- For N level tree it needs `2^N-1` memory space.
- If current node is `i` then it's parent is `(i-1)/2`

Example:

```
           2
      7        5
    2   6    X    9
   X X 5 11      4  X
```

Array should be: {2, 7, 5, 2, 6, -1, 9, -1, -1, 5, 11, -1, -1, 4, -1}

There are other ways, but this is very common.
I hope this answers your question because it is somewhat obscure.

For code, follow [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-array-implementation/).

Comment: Not quite right. The parent is `(i-1)/2`. For example, the root node is at position 0. Its children are at `(2*i)+1` and `(2*i+2)`. So the children are 1 and 2. The parent of 2 is 0, but if you just used `i/2`, you'd get a parent value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

The input string seems to present a pre-order traversal of the tree.

So an algorithm would typically use recursion or a stack to unwind that string into an actual node-based tree structure.

Here is some code:

```
import java.util.*; 

class Node {
    char val;
    Node left = null;
    Node right = null;

    Node(char val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    static Node fromString(String str) {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
        Node node = new Node(' ');
        Node stub = node;
        boolean goRight = false;

        for (int i = 0, n = str.length() ; i < n ; i++) { 
            char c = str.charAt(i); 
            if (c == 'x') {
                if (goRight) {
                    node.right = null;
                    node = stack.pop();
                } else {
                    node.left = null;
                    goRight = true;
                }
            } else {
                Node child = new Node(c);
                if (goRight) {
                    node.right = child;
                    node = node.right;
                    goRight = false;
                } else {
                    node.left = child;
                    stack.push(node);
                    node = node.left;
                }
            }
        }
        return stub.left;
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Node root = Node.fromString("AAAxxxAxx");
```

This would lead to the following object structure:

```
{
    "val": 'A',
    "left": {
        "val": 'A',
        "left": { "val": 'A' }
    }, 
    "right": { "val": 'A' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leetcode problems in their test cases represent binary trees as arrays. For example array [3,9,20,null,null,15,7] can be represented as:

```
TreeNode root = Tree.ints(TreeNode.class, "[3,9,20,null,null,15,7]");
Tree.print(root);
//           3
//       ┌───┴───┐
//       9      20
//             ┌─┴─┐
//            15   7
```

where explanation of this representation is:

```
                    left child
                    of root
                      │ 
                      │    right child
                      │    of root
                      │     │
                      ⍒     ⍒
array values:  ┌ 3,   9,   20, null, null,   15,   7 ┐
               │ ----------------------------------- │
array indices: └ 0,   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,   6 ┘
                 ⍋
                 │
                root 


Tree representation of defined array, where values in brackets are array indices:
           3(0)
       ┌───┴───┐
    (1)9      20(2)
             ┌─┴─┐
         (5)15   7(6)
```